# why can't I get rid of these files on git?

Tags: git

I have a few files on git, which are probably residues from Word documents that I used on another computer.

I managed to mark them as deleted, but no matter what I do, I can't get rid of them whenever I type in `git commit`. They are always there.

It seems like the filenames are special, and maybe that's causing the issue because they have `~$` in them.

For example:

```
$ git commit
On branch master
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 2 commits.
  (use "git push" to publish your local commits)

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add/rm <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git restore <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
deleted:    ~$form.docx
deleted:    dir/~$form2.docx
```

How do I get rid of these files from my deleted list?

I should mention that adding them to `.gitignore` doesn't help either. It is as if `~$`, no matter how you escape it, doesn't want to go away.

Comment: Please, try this: `echo '~*' >> .gitignore`.Also, try this: `git rm --cached <file-name>` or `git rm -r --cached <folder-name>`

Answer (score 2):

To commit deletions, you need to “add” them so that they’re staged:

```
git add -A
git commit
```